# How to proceed with a data node with corrupt disk file system

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I would really appreciate help on the correct course of action. The setup is 3 ELK nodes which have all roles.

No shard replication is done. Node 3 experienced a failure on the disk which contains the data folder. An old copy (about a month) of that folder exists, and I know it would not be sufficient to copy the data in.

My question is, what is the correct course of action at this point which would return the stack to normal operation mode:

1. install a new disk and just launch the node? By a strike of luck, that was our least important data.
2. install the new disk and copy the old data and see if it can recover that data?

Also, would doing option 1, while launching an experimental node on which the data folder is mounted and restore whichever recoverable data and re-index them remotely to the original cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to try to use the [`bin/elasticsearch-shard`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-tool.html) tool to see if you can repair part of the data.

Comment: How can I run bin/elasticsearch-shard when I am using docker. As the documentation says, I need to stop elastic before running and I cannot install elastic on the server I am using it from. Is it possible to do that through docker?

Comment: Also, can I first try to run the node and then try elasticsearch-shard if the situation is too bad, or am I risking the cluster health?

Comment: It's always best to create regular snapshots, which makes it dead easy to restore a cluster than having to mess with raw data folders. But as I understand you're not interested in trying to fix the corrupted data, right?

Comment: I understand that. However, we also lost the snapshots as they were on the same drive. Well, we discovered that that there are missing indexes that we need. we can pull them from cold storage, but it will be a long time to finish doing that. I am also concerned whether running the node will affect the whole cluster? the other 2 nodes are running just fine at the moment and I am worried running node 2 with that folder might disrupt or even corrupt the state of the cluster as it was master node at that point.

Comment: I still haven't run the node since the incident. will running it with the old data folder affect the cluster or the other nodes?

Comment: I think if you don't really care about the data, you should just empty the data folder, and launch the node, and it will receive the data and the cluster state from the other two remaining nodes. It's like launching a new empty node.